# The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely fashion

Tags: sql-server

I have an application that use sql server as our database server.
Sometimes, the users encounter the error:
`The request failed or the service did not respond in a timely` fashion in their client app.
The error happens only with `insert` query.
The problem can be solved by restarting the sql server. 
But the frequency now is getting more than before. 
I have increased the service response time but it did not help.
I have moved the database to another machine to test but the same error occur again.

Comment: have you tried to increase the SQL execution timeout? I'd offer other suggestions but you haven't given us any clue to what your code is doing

Comment: @Tanner Yes, I have increased it but it did not help. After increasing, the client app hang longer but after hanging out, it's still showing the error

Comment: Going to have to give us some more clues pal. Have you tracked down the problem SQL? Can you run it in SQL directly? Does it hang there? Have you checked to see if anything is blocking it? etc. etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is old but I wanted to write an answer for this.
This error cause by SQL Server overload (usually the query result is not in memory) so it started to search for a result in disk.
To solve this, you need to reduce the query result if necessary, reindex tables, especially select query